# What is the type of a pi type?

Tags: types, dependent-type

Dependently types languages provide "pi types", that allow types to depend on the value of an input. My question is, what is the *type* of the pi type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a type is a universe. Usually, universes get stratified into levels like Type 0, Type 1, Type 2..., where the type of Type n is Type (n+1). The reason for this is that if we just had one level Type, the type of Type would have to be Type, which often [leads to paradoxes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18089/what-is-the-manner-of-inconsistency-of-girards-paradox-in-martin-lof-type-theor).

So what is the type of `forall a: A, P a` (a pi type using Coq syntax)? If we assume that `A: Type m` and `P: A -> Type n`, we have `forall a: A, P a: Type max(m, n)`. If we have cumulative universes (as Coq does), so that `m≤n` and `A: Type m` implies `A: Type n`, then really the type of `forall a: A, P a` is any universe that's larger than both `m` and `n`.

EDIT: In response to your comment, `->` takes as arguments `A: Type m` and `P: A -> Type n` and returns `forall a: A, P a`, whose type is `Type max(m, n)`, so the type of the pi constructor is `forall (A: Type m) (P: A -> Type n), Type max(m, n)`, or, in Agda syntax, `(A: Set m) (P: A -> Set n) -> Set max(m, n)`.

Comment: I was thinking about the type of the Pi type constructor. E.g., in Agda, you write `(a : Set) -> f a`. My question isn't what the type of that is, but what the type of `(->)` is.

Answer (score 0):

In the lambda cube, Pi Types are formed with the `form` rule:

```
G ⊢ A: s1   G, x: A ⊢ B : s2
--------------------------------- (form)
G ⊢ Πx : A. B: s2
```

Where {s1, s2} can be

1. {*, *} (STLC)
2. {*, □} (dependnet types)
3. {□, □} (type constructor)
4. {□, *} (parametric polymorphism)

This `form` rule can be further generalized in the Pure Type System